# Why didn't Ted just jump off the tower?

Tags: plot-explanation, ted

In **[*Ted*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_(film))**, Ted is climbing up a tower at a baseball stadium being chased by Donny. Eventually Donny grabs him and tears him in half. But my question is **why didn't Ted just jump off the tower?**

He's a teddy bear so he wouldn't have been hurt and it would have meant that he got away from Donny as he couldn't follow. So is there any explanation of why he didn't? Has Seth MacFarlane or anyone else said anything?

Comment: Who says he wouldn't have been hurt? He might not have been severely injured, but I'm sure Ted feels pain.

Comment: @HorusKol when ted is stabbed by Donny in Ted 2, he doesn't feel pain https://watch32hd.co/watch?v=Ted_2_2015 at 1:34:00

Comment: I haven't seen Ted 2 - but he reacts as if hurt during the fistfight with John.

Comment: @HorusKol he isn't hurt, he's sad that their friendship is over

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I'm pretty sure this entire site is spoilers

Answer (score 2):

Ted might not feel pain. But he certainly perceives it. That's the reason why he punches back and also gets scared of things. 
He might not have been hurt if he had jumped off. But he does not see it that way. he sees himself as a human-like teddy bear who can feel pain. He knows the emotion of fear. So he fears losing his life if he falls off a great height.